# How to add multiple instances of identical JPanels

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I want to add on the same frame multiple instances of the same component which extends JPanel but unfortunately when I compile the code it adds on the frame only the last instance.

Here is my main class which extends JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Interface extends JFrame
{
    JPanel jPanel;
    JPanel jPanel02;
    JPanel jPanel03;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        new Interface( );
    }

    public Interface( )
    {

        setTitle( "Tile" );
        setSize( 300, 300 );
        setVisible( true );

        jPanel = new MyOwnJPanel( "My Own JPanel 01" );
        jPanel02 =  new MyOwnJPanel( "My Own JPanel 02" );
        jPanel03 =  new MyOwnJPanel( "My Own JPanel 03" );


        add( jPanel );
        add( jPanel02 );
        add(jPanel03);

    }
}
```

And here is the class which extends JPanel:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * 
 */
public class MyOwnJPanel extends JPanel
{
    JLabel jLabel;

    MyOwnJPanel(String headerTitle){
        jLabel = new JLabel( headerTitle );
        add(jLabel );
    }

}
```

So, even though I add all three panels, on the frame appears only one, the last one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are adding jpanels at the same location so you are seeing the last one. Try setting borderlayout to jframe. I think you will see all panels.

Edit: Working code is below:

```
setTitle( "Tile" );
        setSize( 300, 300 );
        setVisible( true );

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jPanel = new MyOwnJPanel( "My Own JPanel 01" );
        jPanel02 =  new MyOwnJPanel( "My Own JPanel 02" );
        jPanel03 =  new MyOwnJPanel( "My Own JPanel 03" );


        add( jPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        add( jPanel02, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        add(jPanel03, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I did it but unfortunately It didn't work. The problem is that sometimes appears no JPanel on the frame.

Comment: @RusuRaducu I have edited my post. It is working, can you try it?

Comment: Thank you! It works but It seems to be a problem. The labels appear only after I expand a little bit the frame (1 px). Even though the frame is large enough.

Comment: Try borderlayout in the MyOwnJPanel class also like Interface class. Set label position to BorderLayout.CENTER. You will see label at the center of jpanels.

Comment: I had to type the method  setVisible( true ) after I had added the JPanel components on the frame. Anyway. Thank you very much for your help. You helped me a lot. :)